# SELECT selective records per day

Tags: php, mysql

I have some typical issue here in mysql.
I have this table and I need a query that will extract 2 records per day where employee_id's are being changed.
[Image of DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPTES.png)

So I need the out put like this.

```
  employee_id         employee_id2     fuel_expense       date_created
        1                    9             1230            2017-08-28     
        3                    11            1130            2017-08-28
```

here is my code

```
SELECT `date_created`,`fuel_expense`, COUNT(`date_created`) Counts
  FROM `sales` 
 GROUP BY `date_created`
HAVING COUNT(`date_created`) >=2 ;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be good to show the code you've been working on.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far. Then will help you

Comment: I've edited the question..

Comment: but it is showing me only one record of `2017-08-28`

Comment: #Rick Liguz #Arun ???

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your sql command:

1. Add extra employee_id, employee_id2 columns.
2. Alter sequence of columns to match output
3. Change HAVING condition to COUNT(`date_created`) >=1.
4. Add employee_id to GROUP BY.

SQL below, followed by test case in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7908/11) to prove output as requested.

```
SELECT  `employee_id`, 
    `employee_id2`,
    `fuel_expense`,
    `date_created`,
    COUNT(`date_created`) Counts
     FROM `sales` 
     GROUP BY `date_created`,`employee_id`
    HAVING COUNT(`date_created`) >=1 ;
```

[image: SQLFiddle.com example of solution]